# Do salt rooms really help fight pollen allergies?

Tags: allergy, pollen, salt, breathing

I've heard that sitting in salt rooms, also known as [halotherapy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halotherapy), can help fight pollen allergies. Is there any scientific proof that this claim is true? If so, why?

Comment: what is a "salt room"?

Comment: It is a room full of alt aerosol which penetrates your nasal and respiratory passageways. image of a salt room https://myautisticmuslimchild.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/salt-room.jpeg